# Importing BootstrapVue 3

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, import, bootstrap-vue

[Here You can find the code with image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Af37F.png)

import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import BootstrapVue3 from "bootstrap-vue-3"

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue-3/dist/bootstrap-vue-3.css'

const app = createApp(App);

app.use(BootstrapVue3);

app.mount("#app");

> It Causes an error in a given line of code as following

```
app.use(BootstrapVue3);

Argument of type 'Plugin_2<any[]>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Plugin_2'.
  Type '((app: App<any>, ...options: any[]) => any) & { install?: ((app: App<any>, ...options: any[]) => any) | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'Plugin_2'.
```

Comment: bootstrap-vue-3 is deprecated. It's unknown what are lib versions in your case. If the problem persists, please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This package is deprecated and the repo was moved to bootstrap-vue organization. https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap-vue-3
[image]

Here is the installation process of **bootstrap-vue**

```
# with npm
npm install vue bootstrap bootstrap-vue
# with yarn
npm install vue bootstrap bootstrap-vue
```

Then, register BootstrapVue in your app entry point (typically app.js or main.js)

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import { BootstrapVue, IconsPlugin } from 'bootstrap-vue'

// Import Bootstrap and BootstrapVue CSS files (order is important)
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'

// Make BootstrapVue available throughout your project
Vue.use(BootstrapVue)
// Optionally install the BootstrapVue icon components plugin
Vue.use(IconsPlugin)
```

You can also follow the bellow link. https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs#using-module-bundlers